# Correct and most efficient way to pull data in to a pandas data frame for machine learning

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

Given a data frame as follows

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 y
2  3  4  5  5  7  11.32
3  4  5  3  2  3  10.99
```

With a lot more data in, say 1000 rows.

What is the most efficient and effective way to read in this data in to a correct X, y split?

Thanks, J.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need to extract values from the last column and features from the all other columns. You could use [`iloc`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjng9a1uYPLAhULCSwKHWwYA9wQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.DataFrame.iloc.html&usg=AFQjCNHdB3S4iWPaSmfS-DOX8Ip8Grk0XQ&bvm=bv.114733917,d.bGg) with integer indices and [`values`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjLzf69uYPLAhWIESwKHZJQBXwQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.DataFrame.values.html&usg=AFQjCNGy_EAMTIY_1NDN87wEAPtF4Bq32Q&bvm=bv.114733917,d.bGg) for that:

```
y = df.iloc[:, -1].values
X = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
```

So for your example:

```
In [153]: X
Out[153]:
array([[2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7],
       [3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3]], dtype=int64)

In [154]: y
Out[154]: array([ 11.32,  10.99])
```

Usually for `scikit-learn` methods you could pass dataframes and series, so for that you could omit `values` attribute:

```
y = df.iloc[:, -1]
X = df.iloc[:, :-1]

In [156]: X
Out[156]:
   x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6
0   2   3   4   5   5   7
1   3   4   5   3   2   3

In [157]: y
Out[157]:
0    11.32
1    10.99
Name: y, dtype: float64
```